# Multisite blog post creation in Kentico CMS

Tags: asp.net, kentico, kentico-mvc

I need some guidance on how to achieve the following functionality on the Kentico Xperience 13.
The goal is to be able to create a blog post (article page) and have a dropdown to select the category of the post and more importantly to select the sites that this blog post will go into.
For example:  I manage content on 20 sites via an admin portal and I want to post a blog post to 10 of the sites, I currently will have to go into the admin portion of each site and perform the same operation for each, it would be helpful to do it once and select multiple sites on the same page (via dropdown check-box widget for example) and publish in one go.

Any guidance on how to accomplish this is much appreciated!

Comment: Kentico offers an API that you can consume, and lots of documentation about how to do so. Stack Overflow isn't here to write your code for you. It's on you to research how to do this, make an attempt at solving it, and then if you get stuck you can create a [mcve] and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt in a question.

Comment: Sure, you can come here to gain and share knowledge, but that does not mean that it's a freeform exchange. We have specific expectations regarding the types of questions to be asked and how they should be asked. You didn't explicitly ask us to write the code, but the implication is there, whether you intended it or not. Stack Overflow isn't somewhere you just come to say "How do I do X?" Take the time to research the available options to you, and try to actually implement a solution. If you have a specific question regarding your implementation, that would make for a more appropriate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your blog post (article page) page type could have a multiple select dropdown/checkbox list of sites (if that is how you'd want to specify the sites to duplicate to). Then when the page is saved/inserted, you could have a [global event](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/handling-global-events) set up which duplicates the blog post into the given sites.

Or, instead of having a global event/site selection field combination, you could make a [custom module](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/creating-custom-modules) which is dedicated to duplicating pages to other sites.  Maybe the module could allow you to select multiple pages you want to duplicate, and the sites you want to duplicate to.

Comment: Yep seems like it will have to be a combo of a global event handler and a custom module. I appreciate your help, thank you!